# How to stop the “Your version of Windows 10 has reached its end of service.” message? I do not want to update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, privacy, windows-10-upgrade, unwanted-application

And I know for sure that it was for years reported that I don't have to update Windows to a new version: I know that so clearly because that was basically the only thing stoppable for an end user in the field of security updates.

Has Microsoft changed this - the possibility to NOT upgrade to a new version?

Could I stop it?

The OS message told to I have three choices:

- Restart in the evening.
- Set a time to restart.
- And Restart now?

Could I do anything to select:

- No restart ever for this upgrade???

Has this to do with the forced emergency update a couple of days ago? The background update process started, and while it was usually possible to stop it by cutting the internet connection, and after reconnecting the update process didn't restart, a couple of days ago the update process immedeatly restarted after reconnecting.

If this is connected to the emergency update, then it would be a reasonable explanation why Microsoft is doing the just now showing up forced version upgrade on an official and legal and obligate holiday. Where should an end user get any professional support on such a day?

Well, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: “…on an official and legal and obligate holiday.” Most people would actually like to get updates on holidays are off hours. Let the system do what it needs to without interfering with daily work. That said, Christmas might be a holiday to some but not for all. It’s the 7th day of Hanukkah for me and doesn’t require any special “hands off” of work today. It is also Sunday today in the U.S. so that alone would mean less work hours. So please, if you are upset at this update that is fine. But please do not mix faith and holidays into your frustration.

Comment: I just removed your [recent edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1759463/revisions) that was a rant that ended: “And NOT fire the action forced on the next shutdown on a legal holiday!” Voting to close this. Your anger bellies anyone’s ability to assist you here and your endless obsession with this happening on a “legal holiday” is ridiculous. I had to patch a bunch of Linux servers last week at the during Hanukkah which is the “legal holiday.” Did I endlessly rant about my holiday happening during this? No. You have answers that explain this. Sorry but no sympathies to this question any more.

Comment: And I just rolled back yet another edit that had this line: “I also can't add a comment because of only having 11 points on this system currently.” You can comment on your own question! In fact you [already commented on this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1759463/how-to-stop-the-your-version-of-windows-10-has-reached-its-end-of-service-mes#comment2734749_1759464). You also stated, “Microsoft paid emlpoyee at work it seems.” Give me a break. I use macOS and Linux and could care less about Microsoft versus OS nonsense. Your question is just a frustrated rant despite answers provided.

Answer (score 1):

This message means that your version of Windows has become too old
and no longer receives security updates.
You’re seeing this notification because your version of Windows 10
is out of service. Windows attempted to update this device several
times, but it hasn’t received an update in a significant amount of
time.

Nothing stops you from ignoring the message and continue permanently
using your Windows version, but you're running a security risk :
Your computer is exposed to any known security weak spot, so will
run a significant  risk anytime that you connect to the internet.

I don't know if anything prevents your upgrading to the newest
Windows 10 version, but my very strong recommendation is to do
the upgrade.

If you're worried about the upgrade causing problems, you may backup
your disk and create a rescue boot disk for restoring the disk to its
current value. For example, use
[AOMEI Backupper Free](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html)
and its
[boot media](https://www.ubackup.com/help/create-bootable-disk.html).

If you instead decide to stay with your version and disable the
warning, you may locate and remove the notification software listed
in the article
[End of servicing notification for Windows 10 Versions 1507, 1511, and 1607](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/end-of-servicing-notification-for-windows-10-versions-1507-1511-and-1607-44bd4e17-991c-c27f-5f97-449bced9a1c3).
But I do not recommend this.

Comment: And just to clarify, this doesn't mean you need to install Windows 11. You just need to install a more recent version of Windows 10, via Windows Updates.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a Corporate machine (that is, you have your own individual machine), you cannot turn this message off permanently.

You will have to accept that Microsoft changes this and forces you to update.

You cannot simply decline updates on any kind of long term basis.

You cannot stop a restart. That, too, is inevitable. You cannot update any other software in this state, and at some point restart will have to happen.

So update and get on with it.

Comment: If it is like that, then it is like that. That's true. ): - I just wondered, as I'm ABSOLUTLY and POSITIVLY sure, that explicitly not agreeing to upgrades was possible, and basically the only thing (of all important automatic updates) an end-user was able to decline.

Comment: “Permanent “ in the world of computers lasts about 6 months and then you must move

Answer (score 0):

Not to update your own Win10-System will bring you alot of trouble concerning cybersecurity.

There is a way to stop every Win-Update, but no way to stop that at all.
At some point, the *Service Control Manager* will bring back to life the whole WinUpdate-scenario.
this is only recommended when you have an offline computer.

But if you are online all the time, on the Internet, then I advise you to update your system immediately, otherwise you will have serious security gaps.
And unsecured on the internet is generally not advisable.